# How can I use collection_select in form_for to select models with specific attribute in array of attributes? Rails 5 Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model-view-controller, activerecord

So I am trying to make a form that has a

```
f.collection_select
```

where instead of calling `Model.all` I call `Model.find_by(roles: "site_admin")` but I after spending a lifetime in the rails console I cant seem to figure it out.

... models ...

```
Class User 
  has_many :listings
  petergate(roles: [:site_admin], multiple: true)
end 

class Listing
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm using the [petergate](https://github.com/elorest/petergate) gem to give User a attribute of roles which can be :site_admin, or :user

rails console

```
irb(main):001:0> User.first.roles
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> [:site_admin, :user]
```

My form

```
<%= f.label :listing_agent %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :name ) %>
```

This works, but in the drop down menu it displays all users from the `User.all`

My *question* is, is there a way that I instead of calling `User.all` can I call something like `User.find_by(roles: "site_admin")` in order to display only the users who have the role of :site_admin?

I've been in the rails console trying every possible combination in order to select the role but I can't seem to get it.

I'm thinking that maybe its something with the petergate gem, and that the roles attritubute is :site_admin as a symbol, not "site_admin" as a string.

I've also tried in the form

```
 <%= f.collection_select((:user_id, User.all, :id, :name) if user.roles.first === :site_admin ) %>

 <%= f.collection_select((:user_id, ( User.all.map { |user| user if user.roles.first === :site_admin } ), :id, :name) if user.roles.first === :site_admin ) %>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here besides having to add a whole new column to the Users table in the DB that I can make a query against. TIA

Comment: Have you tried `User.where(roles: 'site_admin')`, `find_by` and `find` return single value if present. If you have multiple users with `site_admin` role use where.

Comment: yes, and i get what seems to be like an object. `irb(main):002:0> User.where(roles: "site_admin")
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."roles" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["roles", "--- site_admin\n"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Comment: that last query seems to be fine, the thing is that it's empty. Why is it empty ?, roles are serialized in the database, do you see `["roles", "--- site_admin\n"]` ?. Try maybe with `where("roles like ?", "% site_admin\n%")`

Comment: I get the same answer when i do that `irb(main):001:0> User.where("roles like ?", "% site_admin\n%")
  User Load (3.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (roles like '% site_admin
%') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
irb(main):002:0>`